# UISplitView with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app containing overview (table view) and multiple detail views (different kinds of views). For the purpose of modularity, all detail views use separate storyboards.

Now I need to make my app universal. For that, I want to use an `UISplitView` with the overview as master view and load the details views on the right. However, I am not sure that it is possible to do it with my multiple storyboards.

What are my possibilities? I have to keep the app modular. I have already separate storyboards for iPhone and iPad but that doesn't really help me yet.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that someone else is interested on the topic... I got it working.

I just instantiate the controller I need from the storyboard where it is located and load it in the detail view (similarly to the `MuptipleDetailViews` sample). Of course, I had to adjust the entire navigation related to the respective controllers and, especially, to modify the methods for taps on controls and table cells.

Hope that will help someone else working on iPad apps. :)