# Swift UISplitViewController with multiple storyboards for Detail View

Tags: xcode, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have been struggling with this issue for days and cannot get it to work. Read multiple SO posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689413/uisplitviewcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller-doesnt-work-properly-with-mult), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175785/uisplitview-with-multiple-storyboards), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104404/uisplitviewcontroller-with-multiple-detail-view-controller), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538231/ios-uisplitviewcontroller-with-storyboard-multiple-master-views-and-multiple), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462955/uisplitview-with-multiple-viewcontrollers-in-detailview-storyboard) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift)). Asked my friend Google, helped to understand the problem but not to solve it yet.

In the first version of my iOS app (Swift2 and XCode7) I use a UITableViewController and UINavigationViewController to load new content from a different UIStoryboard. This all works fine. For the second version of this app I want to implement a UISplitViewController and now I am getting the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller as a child of view controller:

I understand the hint, but cannot solve it in a way that works either in portrait and landscape mode. Moreover, the sort of solution I had did not use the UINavigationController in the landscape orientation.

I created a test project to track down this error, hoping to solve it.

This is the code that generates the error:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ThirdScreen", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ThirdDetailViewController
    controller.title = "Miracle!"
    splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(controller, sender: nil)
```

The full code of this test project is [available from GitHub](https://github.com/DigNeurosurgeon/TestMasterDetail/).

How can I make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, the trick is to remove the segue and use a storyboard reference like this:

[image: storyboard reference]

For testing and teaching purposes, I created a complete test project which is [available from GitHub](https://github.com/DigNeurosurgeon/MasterDetailStoryboards). This demonstrates the use of multiple storyboards for the detail view.

Update Nov 28: this solution works but requires iOS 9. It is perfectly possible to use another UIViewController as a DetailViewController (meaning the template can be used) as long as you remove the segue, implement `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and use the code from the example. In the latter case, it also works on iOS 8.